# what is the content of cl_platform_id data structure?

Tags: opencl

I understand that `cl_platform_id` is a data structure like:

```
typedef struct{
   foo1 bar1;
   foo2 bar2;
   ...;
}cl_platform_id;
```

But what are the content of this structure? for example if I want to print these content to the console what data type should I use?

I tried integer but I got the error:

> warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
>         'cl_platform_id' (aka 'struct _cl_platform_id *') [-Wformat]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The `cl_platform_id` is an abstract (opaque) type, it is not intended to be directly used. Instead, query the information that you want to know with  [clGetPlatformInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformInfo.html) on your `cl_platform_id`. You can get strings (like  `CL_PLATFORM_NAME`) that you can then print.

Comment: Can you be so kind to point me towards a source code implementing `cl_platform_id`?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the [w-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463796/w-m)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50666450/4999991) I was pointed towards the right direction and was to write a snippet to print the platform information:

```
cl_platform_info Param_Name[5]={CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE, CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS};
cl_platform_info param_name;
size_t param_value_size;
for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
  param_name=Param_Name[j];
  err = clGetPlatformInfo( platforms[i], param_name, 0, NULL, &param_value_size);
  char* param_value = (char*)malloc( sizeof(char) * param_value_size);
  err = clGetPlatformInfo( platforms[i], param_name, param_value_size, param_value, NULL );
  printf("%s\n", param_value);
  free(param_value);
}
```

The complete code can be found here in [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/3ca81a9b6f4b5c51e93dcee34b434342).