# clGetDeviceIDs() function causes heap memory corruption when fetching OpenCL device IDs

Tags: c, windows, runtime-error, opencl, heap-corruption

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62286806/4999991), I'm trying to compile and test [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/3ae03a58da81abfaaef4a0fde606701f). But I get heap memory corruption error at runtime:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Debug Error!
Program: ...

HEAP CORRUPTION DTECTED: after Normal block ... at ...
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after the end of heap buffer

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

But when pressing `Retry` as instructed the program seem to finish successfully with no erros/warnings or unexpected outputs.

A brief version of the `main.c` code:

```c
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120

#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit, EXIT_FAILURE

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cl_int err;
    cl_uint numPlatforms = 0;
    cl_platform_id *platforms;

    err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);

    platforms = (cl_platform_id *)malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) * numPlatforms);

    cl_uint *numDevices = (cl_uint *)malloc(sizeof(cl_uint) * numPlatforms);
    cl_device_id **devices = (cl_device_id **)malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id **) * numPlatforms);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numPlatforms; i++)
    {
        err = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &numDevices[i]);

        devices[i] = (cl_device_id *)malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id *) * numDevices[i]);

        for (size_t j = 0; j < numDevices[i]; j++)
        {

            err = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, numDevices[i], (devices[i] + j), NULL);
        }
        free(devices[i]);
    }


    free(devices);
    free(numDevices);
    free(platforms);
    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id *) * numDevices[i]);` -> `malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id) * numDevices[i]);`

Comment: Similarly the preceding `malloc` is also incorrect but doesn't cause problems because the size ends up to be the same. `malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id **) * numPlatforms);` -> `malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id *) * numPlatforms);`

Comment: @kaylum I must have been bran damaged or something last night. Thanks. There were other issues as well. fixed them. Will updated the Gist.